# REST parameter validation

Tags: java, spring, rest

Is there a way to specifically mention the length for the request parameter? My Parameter could be of length 4 or 6 .. 
But specifying like below :
@Size(min=4, max=6)
@RequestParam String param1

Would allow length 5 too which is invalid in my case ? Is there a way to accomplish this without a customer validator?

Thanks

Comment: ``Is there a way to accomplish this without a custom validator?`` No, I don't think. But that is trivial to implement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use `@Pattern` annotation which verifies that string follows specific regexp.

Then, you need to build regexp that will be something like this - `^(?=[0-9]*$)(?:.{4}|.{6})$` (checks that string contains only 4 digits or 6 digits).

[Pattern annotation docs](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/api/org/hibernate/validator/Pattern.html)